# Would blindsight allow a blinded caster to cast spells that specify the target as a creature "that you can see"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, special-senses, blind

Would **blindsight** allow a blinded caster to cast spells that specify the target as a creature "that you can see"?

Would **blindsight** be able to substitute for the requirement of having to see a creature to target it (assuming the target was within the range of the caster's blindsight and spell)?

Let's assuming I'm playing a character who is blind, but also has "blindsight" out to 10'ft.  Blindsight would let me know where a creature is near me, and even make melee attacks without disadvantage.  Would it let me target a spell at that same creature?

Alternately, if an old blind dragon with blindsight wanted to use an ability or power that requires them to be able to see a target, could they still use it?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it’s been asked before.